# pdanet from laptop to cell phone. pdanet reports failed to connect to (60). Bluetooth not detected on your phone

Tags: windows-7, android, bluetooth, tethering

I am able to Bluetooth tether from my laptop to my galaxy s6, leveraging my s6's internet connection.

However, on another laptop, when I try to pair my phone with the PC via pdanet, pdanet reports "failed to connect to  (60). Bluetooth not detected on your phone".

I have "activate Bluetooth mode" checked on my cell phone, and Bluetooth enabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use the built in WiFi Hotspot?

Comment: I have Sprint, so I would have to pay for it :(